# Calculating the radius of a cone, given only the area and volume

Tags: geometry

I have a question about maths.

**Calculate the radius of the cone, if Area = 9π and Volume = 2π.**

I have tried turning around virtually everything, but cannot seem to succeed. Basically what I did was to try and equalize the area of the circle in the area formula with the area of the circle in the volume formula, I have also tried using the Pythagoras theorem to replace s with r and h, but I always end up with two variables in a single equation. The two equations that I kinda "derived" with the data are:

**9 = r² + rs**  … from area

**6 = r²h**  … from volume

Base formulas as a reminder:

**A = πr² + πrs**     … where s is the length of the side and r is the radius

**V = (πr² * h) / 3**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You have three unknowns: $r,h,s$. You have two equations. Can you think of a third equation relating these three quantities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$ we get $$h=\frac{3V}{\pi r^2}$$ and 
$$A=\pi r^2+\pi r\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$$
and you have to solve
$$A=\pi r^2+\pi r\sqrt{r^2+\frac{9V^2}{\pi^2 r^4}}$$
squaring we get
$$A^2-2A\pi r^2=\frac{9V^2\pi}{r^2}$$
you can solve a quartic
$$r=1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt {A\pi\, \left( {A}^{2}+\sqrt {-72\,A{\pi}^{2}{V}^{2
}+{A}^{4}} \right) }}{A\pi}}
$$

Comment: Thanks, totally worked. Realised that what I did was completely illogical, as I replaced the r in the pi*r*s and was left with 3 variables. Thank you. Your way I managed to get to the end equation.